# How can i replace part of a column name with a dict in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have column names such as :

```
ab_sells_cde_104_frm, ab_sells_cde_105_frm, ab_sells_cde_120_frm
```

i also have a dict like:

```
dict_2 = {'115': 'SERVICES',
 '116': 'HEA',
 '117': 'HOME',
 '104': 'AI'}
```

I wish to replace the 3 digits in column headers with this dict. I am unsure how i have tried:

```
df.replace(dict_2, regex=True)
```

This deoesn't do anything. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Index.to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_series.html) for convert columns to `Series` with [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
c = 'ab_sells_cde_104_frm, ab_sells_cde_105_frm, ab_sells_cde_120_frm'.split(', ')
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=c)

dict_2 = {'115': 'SERVICES',
 '116': 'HEA',
 '117': 'HOME',
 '104': 'AI'} 

df.columns = df.columns.to_series().replace(dict_2, regex=True)
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ab_sells_cde_AI_frm, ab_sells_cde_105_frm, ab_sells_cde_120_frm]
Index: []
```

Or if need replace by call back by [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('\d+', lambda x: dict_2.get(x.group(0), x.group(0)), regex=True)

print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ab_sells_cde_AI_frm, ab_sells_cde_105_frm, ab_sells_cde_120_frm]
Index: []
```

Replace with inteegrs with length `3`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('\d{3}', lambda x: dict_2.get(x.group(0), x.group(0)), regex=True)

print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ab_sells_cde_AI_frm, ab_sells_cde_105_frm, ab_sells_cde_120_frm]
Index: []
```

Comment: be careful, if there are overlapping codes (e.g. 1104), this will cause a partial match ('1AI')

Comment: @mozway - OK, added new solution, but still not sure if replacement only first 3 digits

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple list comprehension with `re.sub`:

```
import re
df.columns = [re.sub('\d+', lambda m: dict_2.get(m.group(0), m.group(0)), s)
              for s in df.columns]
```

output:

```
  ab_sells_cde_AI_frm ab_sells_cde_105_frm ab_sells_cde_120_frm
0                  NA                   NA                   NA
```